# How to interact trought a UI with a python script

Tags: python, java, android, html

I created a prototype of a small rover with a raspberry, using python I created a script that allows me to move it simply by pressing a few keys on the keyboard.

The script essentially waits for a key to be pressed to "command" the rover motors, the code works through a terminal shell, now what I would like is to create a web UI or an Android app that allows me to command the rover without using a shell.

The source code is something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/bin/bash
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

print("\n")
print("A-forward S-backward L-left turn R-right turn  l-low m-medium h-high e-exit")
print("\n")

a=11
b=15
c=16
d=18

def init():    
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(a, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(b, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(c, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(d, GPIO.OUT)
    p=GPIO.PWM(d,1000)
    p.start(25)

def forward():
    init()
    //MORE STUFF

def reverse():
    init()
    //MORE STUFF

def left_turn():
    init()
    //MORE STUFF

def right_turn():
    init()
    //MORE STUFF

while(1):

    x=input()
    if x=='w':
        print("forward")
        forward()
        x='z'

    elif x=='s':
        print("backward")
        reverse()
        x='z'

    elif x=='a':
        print("left")
        left_turn()
        x='z'

    elif x=='d':
        print("right")
        right_turn()
        x='z'

    elif x=='e':
        GPIO.cleanup()
        break

    else:
        print("<<<  wrong data  >>>")
        print("please enter the defined data to continue.....")
```

How can I create a graphical interface (basically formed by 4 buttons that will represent the directions) that can interact with a python script? Is it possible to continue to use a script as a basis for moving my rover or should I implement a different solution?

More than a solution I'm interested in understanding if I can use the base script and if I can hook it to a UI.

Comment: why is it tagged [tag:java], [tag:android] and [tag:html] ? as all of those are not directly linked with your problem, it's only python code here

Comment: because it's part of my question, I in fact asked if it is possible to integrate a python script with a web interface (html) or with an android app (java)

Comment: So the python code doesn't really matter as it can be all code, it will works the same and will be the same question ? it just make people more confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to a simple graphical interface, I would look into **pygame** for simple functionality with buttons and a display for a rover moving.

Personally, I would not recommend pygame for large, intricate projects like game design, but your needs from your question seem viable.

https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/make-a-button-using-pygame-in-python.

If you want to design a website UI, from my experience, you should pick a **framework** such as **Django**.

https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/web-development/responsiveness-with-a-front-end-framework/.
https://www.w3schools.com/django/

After you set up so you can host locally, you should be able to implement your script on a web page where you may have to use javascript or another language for design features.